# IPv4/IPv6 protocol/next header value in empty payload case

Tags: header, protocols, ipv6, ipv4, payload

Which is the value of the protocol field (IPv4 header) or next-header field (IPv6 header) in the case that there is no payload (empty)?

I looked in the [list of protocol numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers) but 0x00 specify a protocol and there aren't special values.

Comment: What is the point of a packet with no payload, and why would you ever send such a thing?

Comment: Just asking if this particular case is foreseen by the IPv4 or IPv6 protocols definition.

Comment: The purpose of the network protocol is to deliver a payload across different networks, so a packet without a payload doesn't make much sense. For IP to communicate with IP without passing to an upper layer, there is ICMP, an integral part of IP that acts as if it were an upper layer protocol, but it is the packet payload, even if it is retained in the network-layer module.